# InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php on laravel 5

Tags: php, url-routing, laravel-5

I am new in laravel5. I generate one application for learning. When I insert data into my contact us page, error will be display. It's  route level error. I can't understand this error.

**Error message**

> InvalidArgumentException in compiled.php line 8545: Route [contactus]
>   not defined.

my code :

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('contactus', 'ContactusController@index');
```

**ContactusController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ContactusModel;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/* namespaces */
use App\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


class ContactusController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        return view('contacts.contact');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        ContactusModel::insertall($input);

        return Redirect::route('contactus')->with('message', 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!');

        //return view('contact.contact');
    }
}
```

**ContactusModel.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class ContactusModel extends Model {


    protected $table = 'contactus_models';


    protected $fillable = array('fullname','mobileno', 'email', 'message');


    public static function insertall($data)
    {       
        return DB::table('contactus_models')->insert(
                array(
                        'fullname' => $data['fullname'],
                        'mobileno' => $data['mobileno'],
                        'email' => $data['email'],
                        'message' => $data['message'],
                        )
            );
    }

}
```

And my view file is under **contacts** folder which name is **contact.blade.php**

Can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest using in built Create method to fill in data into table instead of creating your own method for the same task. That is not the solution of your problem but yes you should use the framework to the fullest.

Answer (score 1):

changing it

```
return Redirect::route('contactus')->with('message', 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!');
```

to

```
return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!');
```

or

```
return Redirect::route('index')->with('message', 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!');
```

`Redirect::route` this mean is route direction.

Comment: return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!'); It's working but message is not display.....
And return Redirect::route('index')->with('message', 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!'); in it, Route [index] not defined. error message display

Comment: you must in view add show flash message, like so `@if(Session::has('message')) {{ Session::get('message') }} @endif`

Comment: I found your view name is `contact.blad.php`, you must be sure it called name `contact.blade.php`

Comment: sorry it's not a problem. i check it is correct as per your suggestion.

Comment: maybe you can try `return Redirect::back()->with(['message' => 'Record Inserted Successfully!!!']);` I'm not sure it is work, but try this. and I found this video can be sloved your problem, it's free https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/20

Answer (score 1):

Yes Finally I get solution.....

Need to change in **Route.php** file..

Change

```
Route::get('contactus', 'ContactusController@index');
```

To

```
Route::get('contactus', array(
    'as' => 'contactus', 'uses' => 'ContactusController@index'
));
```

That's work perfectly....